# How do you make include_path recursive in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a directory structure with a "master" directory of PHP functions, organized into a bunch of directories. I can not seem to include them without explicitly adding each full path to the include_path variable in php.ini. I wish to include ALL directories under the master directory. I am always using full paths, and my "master" directory is /app. 
    `include_path = ".:/app/"` does not work?

Comment: You really should have asked a new question. Now the existing answer doesn't make sense anymore. I'm rolling back the edit.

Comment: To the now removed question: You're pushing elements onto an undefined variable. Try: `var evaluateReturn = []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include file recursively from a folder, you can get a list file from that folder and include the file from that folder.

Here's the simple example to do that, I don't know if this what you want :)

```
$dir    = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\app';
$files = scandir($dir,1);
unset($files[count($files)-1]);
unset($files[count($files)-1]);
foreach ($files as $v){
    include($v);
}
```

For more information about `scandir`, please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).

Answer (score 0):

Include path is not recursive and you cannot have what you need without custom code. Basically you need a function to search for a file recursively and then to build proper include path and then include file.

Comment: Can you disable checking the "Include_path"? I believe the open_basedir is recursive, is it not?